# For which values $r, s \in \mathbb R$ is the set $\{u, v, w\}$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$u = (r,1,1), \ v = (1,s,2s), \ w = (1,2,2)$$

I know to assume the set will be linearly dependent, equate them to the $0$ vector and find the values not equal to what $r$ and $s$ is. But I can't seem to reduce the matrix to echelon form.

I've gotten to the point of:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    r & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & s & 2 \\
    1 & 2s & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$  $R_2 = R_2 - R_3$
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    r & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & -s & 0 \\
    1 & 2s & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ $R_3 = R_3 +2R_2$

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    r & 1& 1 \\
    0 & -s & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

EDIT: Thank you @LordSharktheUnknown

$R_3 = r \times R_3 - R_1$

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    r & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & -s & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 2r-1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

And I'm stuck. I know $s ≠ 0$ for it to be linearly independent but I have no idea how to reduce the rows any further to get to $r$ by itself.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Why not subtract $r$ times the last row from the first row in your final matrix?

Comment: The matrix is nonsingular iff its columns are linearly independent. Try computing its determinant instead.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown In this case you have to consider $r=0$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe No, I don't.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown You’re right, I misread.

Comment: You can try swapping the first and final rows.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I edited this into the post, and tried few other things and can't seem to reduce it any further. Unless I am missing something or is this the final matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the last pre-edit matrix (the edit adds a transformation that changes linear dependence in case $r=0$; it's also not the transformation Lord Shark the Unknown describes).

By development in the second row (is that the correct English term?), one easily calculates the determinant as
$$\det
\begin{pmatrix}
    r & 1& 1 \\
    0 & -s & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
= -s(2r-1)$$
Now the vectors are linearly independent iff the determinant is non-zero, which is the case iff all factors are nonzero. Thus we easily see the conditions:
$$s\ne 0, r\ne \tfrac12$$