# How to show the set {u,v,w} is linearly independent with 2 variables

Tags: matrices

So the vectors are

```
r  1   1 
1  s   2 
1  2s  2
```

For which values of $r,s$ in subset $\mathbb R$ is the set $\{u,v,w\}$ linearly independent?
I got if $s(rs-1)(2r-1)$, does not equal $0$, thus $r$ cannot equal $1/2$, $rs $ cannot equal $1$ and $s$ cannot equal $0$....but i'm feeling $1%$ confident on my answer because the matrices was difficult to reduce to row echelon form
Would appreciate any help,
Thankyou!

Comment: does it mean the System $$ra+b+c=0$$ and $$a+bs+2c=0$$ and $$a+2sb+2c=0$$? solving for $a,b,c$?

Answer (score 0):

This was asked yesterday by someone else. See the answer here

[For which values $r, s \in \mathbb R$ is the set $\{u, v, w\}$ linearly independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2699905/for-which-values-r-s-in-mathbb-r-is-the-set-u-v-w-linearly-independ?rq=1)